# Passing an array from python to C using ctypes, then using that array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, c, ctypes

I am trying to make a `histogram of Poisson random generated variables using Python and C`. I wanted to use `Python for plotting` and `C for generating. This resulted in the following to codes`

Python:

```py
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

lam = 5.0
n = 1000000

def generate_poisson(lam, n):
    array = np.zeros(n, dtype= np.int)
    f = ctypes.CDLL('./generate_poisson.so').gen_poisson
    f(ctypes.c_double(lam), ctypes.c_int(n), ctypes.c_void_p(array.ctypes.data))
    return array

start_time = time.time()
array = generate_poisson(lam,n)
print(time.time() - start_time)

plt.hist(array, bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], density = True)
plt.savefig('fig.png')
print(array)
```

C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

double get_random() { return ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX); }

int poisson_random(double lam){
    int X;
    double prod, U, explam;

    explam = exp(-lam);
    X = 0;
    prod = 1.0;
    while (1){
        U = get_random();
        prod *= U;
        if (prod > explam){
            X+=1;
        }
        else {
            return X;
        }
    }
}

void gen_poisson(double lam, int n, void * arrayv)
{
    int * array = (int *) arrayv;
    int index = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i =0; i<n; i++, index++){
        //printf("before %d\n", array[i]);
        array[index++] = poisson_random(lam);
        //printf("after %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem understanding why this works, or at least it seems to work correctly, occurs inside the for loop in `gen_poisson()`. Somehow using `array[index++]` instead of `array[index]` results in a correct histogram. But I dont really understand why this has to be the case. The code also seems to work when the for loop is changed to

```c
for (int i =0; i<2*n; i++){
        //printf("before %d\n", array[i]);
        array[i++] = poisson_random(lam);
        //printf("after %d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Can someone explain why in this case the loop has to be incremented twice? I just started programming in C while I have some experience in Python. So assume the culprit is my lack of understanding about C. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you clarify in how far it does *not* work without post-incrementing ``index``? The title and tags mention Cython, which generally makes writing correct code much easier, but the question does not seem to include it – do you actually use Cython? In how far is it relevant for your problem?

Comment: You've got an array of C `long`, not `int`.

Comment: Also, [NumPy already has a Poisson distribution sampling function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html).

Comment: I actually meant ctypes instead of Cython. I edited the post, my bad

Comment: I am aware of numpy having a sampling function, I just wanted to try to implement it myself. When I use array[index] the array in python is an array with very big numbers and zero's. I have not access to my computer at the moment and will post an example of the array asap.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.  If I use your C source and first Python code it crashes due to indexing beyond the end of array.  If I use `array[index]` (or just `array[i]`...don't know why you have `i` and `index`) it works.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Interesting, thank you for pointing it out. Got the problem I had fixed by following user2357112 supports Monica comment about changing the array type. This way the index variable is indeed unnecessary and array[i] suffices.

Comment: @ilikemaths did you edit the question and change the array type?  I don't see a change in the edit history, and used what you currently have posted.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I just posted an answer with the updated code for which I got it working. Or would you think it is better to directly edit this in the question?

Comment: Your Python code declared an np.array of `c_int`...so changing to `long*` in the C code makes no sense to me.  Your code worked as is for me, with `int` array and `int*` with the correct indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `gen_poisson` into:

```
void gen_poisson(double lam, int n, void * arrayv)
{
    long * array = (long *) arrayv;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
        array[i] = poisson_random(lam);
    }
}
```

solves the problem. The problem was as pointed out with declaring the array as `int *` instead of `long *`.